# position of UIView after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom UIView subclass without a corresponding UIViewController.  I use this class in various places in my app.  When I rotate the device I need to reposition the view.  I understand this is normally done with the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method, but that's a part of the UIViewController class and not UIView.  My question is, is there a way for my UIView to reposition itself without having to implement a corresponding UIViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you application receives notifications from the device when it rotates.  you can tell the device to begin generating these notifications for you using

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

and then you can register for the notification using

[NSNotificationCenter default] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doThisWhenRotates:) name:addObserver:selector:name:object: object:nil];

HOWEVER, i wouldn't recommend that. if you really want to follow MVC, you should have a controller to handle this type of stuff for the view.

but if you need to, you can do it the way listed above.

Comment: I guess UIAlertView and UIActionSheetView do it with the autoResizeMask setting since they are positioned relative to the window.  In my case I need to position something relative to the navigationBar, and this changes height when you rotate.  Thanks for your help.